# why is it when I try to create a child class from a parent class(Downcasting), I get a null object

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

```
namespace Test
{  
    public class Basic
    {

        public virtual void WriteIt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        }
    }

    public class Not_So_Basic : Basic
    {
        public override void WriteIt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi2");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Not_So_Basic obj = new Basic() as Not_So_Basic;
            if(obj==null)
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            else
            obj.WriteIt();
        }



    }
}
```

So basically I created these two classes, Basic and Not_So_Basic which is a child class of the Basic class.

When I try to create an object of the Not_So_Basic class using an object of its parent class by Downcasting it, I always get a null object.

I understand by doing this, I'm just referencing my child class object to the parent class object and I get that "child class view", right? I'm not really creating a separate space in heap of a child class based off of the parent class.

I'm kind of new at programming so please be gentle, don't roast me. I'm sure there is a rule that I'm breaking. 
Btw I'm trying to learn to program, I'm not working on a project, just trying to wrap my head around a rule that I'm breaking.

The code is written in in c#.

Comment: Because it's not really a `Not_So-Basic` object. The `as` operator just doesn't work that way. And it makes sense from a logical standpoint that you can't treat a base type as a derived type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) attempts to cast, but gives you a `null` object if it can't. So this means the cast failed.

You're casting a `Basic` object to `Not_So_Basic`. You cannot do that because `Basic` does not inherit from `Not_So_Basic`.

To illustrate, all foxes are animals, but not all animals are foxes, so you can't cast an `Animal` to a `Fox`.

That said, if you have an actual `Not_So_Basic` object that's just represented as a `Basic` object, then you can cast it to `Not_So_Basic`. For example:

```
Basic basic = new Not_So_Basic();

Not_So_Basic not_so_basic = (Not_So_Basic) basic; //this works
```

Comment: So basically every time I want to use downcasting from a "parent" based class object to one of its children, I have to make sure the "parent" based class object is pointing to the same type of the "child" class I want to convert it to or and of the "child" class's children?

Comment: Correct. That's why it's runtime exception and not a compiler error - because sometimes it's valid and sometimes it's not. But that's why we have `as` and `is`, so that you can handle a bad cast without an exception.

Comment: Alright, that's it!
Thank you so much!

Everything's perfectly clear now! 
I wish you a wonderful day ^__^

Answer (score 1):

Downcasting is where you take a base class and then try and turn it into a more specific class. This can be accomplished with using `as` like this:

```
Not_So_Basic notSoBasic = basic as Not_So_Basic;
```

The cast will be successful only if `basic` is referring to an instance of `Not_So_Basic`

```
//successful cast
Basic basic = new Not_So_Basic();
Not_So_Basic notSoBasic = basic as Not_So_Basic;
```

OR `basic` is referring to an instance of `Not_So_Basic` child.

```
public class Not_So_Basic_Child : Not_So_Basic
    {
        public override void WriteIt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi from child");
        }
    }

//another successful cast
Basic basic = new Not_So_Basic_Child();
Not_So_Basic notSoBasic = basic as Not_So_Basic;
```

If you are trying to cast an instance of a base class to an instance of a child class, `as` operator will return `null`

```
//unsuccessful cast
Basic basic = new Basic();
Not_So_Basic notSoBasic = basic as Not_So_Basic; //is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Object of Child Class with reference to Parent class, result will be always null. We can not create a child class object like that.

```
//unsuccessful cast
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = parent as Child; //is null
```

Correct way:

```
Parent parent= new Child();
Child  child = (Child) parent; //this works
```